# OMNIKEY 3021 reader returns 6D 00/6A 86 using a Microchip 24LC64SC memory card

Tags: smartcard-reader

Reading from and writing to a Microchip `24LC64SC` memory card using an `OMNIKEY 3021` reader always produces a `6D 00 /6A 86` response. The `APDU's` for reading and writing are very simple:

```
FF B0 00 00 02 response 6A 86 (incorrect p1/p2).
FF D0 00 00 02 01 02 response 6D 00 (invalid instruction).
```

The two APDU's works fine using an `ACR38` reader. However in the case of this reader, it is necessary to select the card type using:

```
FF A4 00 00 01 02 (response 6D 00 from the OMNIKEY reader).
```

The questions are: What are correct `APDU's` for reading and writing those cards? Is it necessary to explicit select the card type? And how is such a card type selection made on the `OMNIKEY` reader?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are no correct APDU's to write these kind of cards. APDU's are only defined for file based smart cards. Those are generally CPU cards that can decode such APDU's. `FF` for a class means it is actually *not* defined by ISO 7816. So in this case your smart card *reader* or reader *library* is interpreting the commands. The interpreted commands make the reader read the memory card. So it's just a convenience layer.

I don't think (but I'm not 100% sure) that this convenience layer is standardized over smart card readers. Anyway, it is better to consult the reader manufacturer and reader manuals.